# what is the difference between iterative and recursive binary search algorithms in case of asymptotic analysis

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, iteration, binary-search

I need to show the differences between the iterative and the recursive binary search algorithms' asymptotic runtime analysis'. as far as i know, they have the same worst case complexity (O(log(n)) but in some resources it says that recursive has O(log(n)+1). I am a bit confused, can somebody help me about this situation?

I also need to improve a python recursive binary search algorithm to run in just as equal time as the iterative one. the code is written below.

thanks!

```
def binarySearch(alist,item):
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = len(alist)/2
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            return True
        else:
            if item<alist[midpoint]:
                return binarySearch(alist[:midpoint],item)
            else:
                return binarySearch(alist[midpoint+1:],item)
```

Comment: Is this for [class](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)? If so, you should note it in the question. As for improving the implementation, what steps have you taken?

Comment: this question is to understand the behaviour of the two algorithms, which will lead me to understand my homework question :) so, this is not for class directly, but will lead me to understand and answer a homework question.

Comment: btw, i didn't do anything to improve, so that i am asking :)

Comment: "steps" doesn't just include specific code improvements. It also includes anything you've done to work towards a solution, which shows that a) you're actively trying and b) where you're getting stuck.

Comment: the ideas i came through is written as comments under the post above. i don't understand why are you questioning this so hardly. i said it is not a homework, i know how to ask homework questions, i read the rules. don't worry :)

Answer (score 2):

O(log(n) + 1) is the same as O(log(n)) -- asymptotically, they produce the same set of functions. The constant addition is ignored, just like constant multiples.

They are different in terms of usage of space -- recursive binary search will use log(n) space (because of the stack) unless the tail-calls are removed by the compiler and turned into a non-recursive definition.

Anyway, your algorithm loses out significantly in performance because slicing is very expensive (O(n)).

Comment: i understand.. how can i slice it better then?

Comment: You can't slice at all. You need a way to represent a subsequence of the list, but without actually copying out all the elements. How might you do that? (I have to be obtuse because I don't know what the homework is)

Comment: i am thinking of taking more parameters like "list, value, first,last" and change the first and last parameters at every call. what about this solution?

Comment: or i might change inside of the outer else block. just to check equality of the midpoint element last but not first.

Comment: @theminyatur The first change is good. The second change would make the algorithm lose correctness unless you did it right.

Comment: i implemented the second option, and checked with the built-in time calculating methods. seems it worked :)

Comment: @theminyatur You still need to make the first change in order to remove the linear factor of time. Checking the equality of the midpoint element last doesn't change the expense of slicing.